# select sub item in a tuple list in python

Tags: python

Here I have one list like this:

`a = [[13245,0.123],[12435,0.435],[12345,0.799],[98775,0.573]...]`

I want to use the first item in every tuple as x axis, and the second item in every tuple as y axis to plot a figure.

like `x = [13245,12435,12345,68775] y = [0.123,0.435,0.799,0.573]`

How can I select them out?

Comment: @MichaelJ.Barber they can be handled exactly the same

Comment: @androyd Very true. But that doesn't make them tuples!

Comment: @MichaelJ.Barber surely not in python, but regarding [this](http://oxforddictionaries.com/definition/tuple?q=tuple) "tuple = a data structure consisting of multiple parts."... Anyway, let this not become a discussion about the meaning of "tuple"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Simplest is probably to use `zip`:

```
x, y = zip(*a)
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
x = [tmplist[0] for tmplist in a]
y = [tmplist[1] for tmplist in a]
```

Also, `[]` doesn't define tuples, but lists. But in your case the handling is equal.

Comment: I can't speak for the downvoter, but I can tell you why I removed my upvote. I think it is quite rude to copy someone else's later answer into yours without any comment to that effect - it looks like you posted my answer earlier than I did, when you just had the fragment defining `x` using a list comprehension.

Comment: *I think it is quite rude to copy someone else's later answer* I didn't. I edited my answer, because I remembered the `zip` function. When you are finished editing the answer, the page is not automatically refreshed, so I was only able to see my own answer. I'm sorry, that it appeared that I copied it, that was definitely not my intention. Since you are so picky about that, I'll update it.

Answer (score 0):

use:

```
x = []
y = []
for e in a:
    x.append(e[0])
    y.append(e[1])
```

edit: I didn't even remeber zip(), but it is certainly the best way of doing it:

```
x, y = zip(*a)
```

Answer (score 0):

python have a realy powerfull function for this :)

zip

try it

```
x,y = zip(*a)
```

the * is the key. see the doc for more details

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure why your converting to a x list and a y list to plot coordinates.  Would something as simple as this work?

```
for x,y in a:
  plot(x,y)
```